# Neural Net gradient calculation with Batch Normalization C++

Tags: c++, neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation, derivative

I was trying to change my activation function of my neural net from sigmoid to RELU (or more specifically SELU). Since I got a lot of exploding gradients with that change, I tried to use the batch normalization. I calculated the gradients of my error function w.r.t the learning parameters \beta and \gamma, but it seems that they are a bit different from the ones I saw in several (sadly only Python) examples.

[Here](https://kratzert.github.io/2016/02/12/understanding-the-gradient-flow-through-the-batch-normalization-layer.html), for example, the code example on the bottom of the page says `dbeta = np.sum(dout, axis=0)` and I wonder what exactly this `dout` is.

My derivatives look like this:

[Derivation of error function w.r.t \beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izgfk.png)

What am I doing wrong in this derivation?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: `dout` is probably delta out, or more specifically, the derivative of the output.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing with delta out, but it's the derivative with respect to what?

Comment: @Toxxiqq It's the derivative of the loss function with respect to the error of the neuron (If final layer), otherwise it is the derivative of the activation function of the layer with respect to the delta of the previous layer (if not final layer).

Comment: It is incredibly hard to find a readable and canonical example of many AI algorithms. Either, because they use GPU technology or they are written in horrible OOP code where the TLDR; flag rises after a short while of reading. Despite being not performant, what should exist is a clear and clean implementation of those algorithms without hidden state and other fun stuff which obscures readability. For backprop: 2 Functions, stateless (`forward(), backward()` where the arguments and outputs reflect anything usually hidden deep in the code.)

Answer (score 0):

I try to add batchnorm2d layer in a small CNN testet on MNIST with Libtorch C++ code with or without GPU use
Here
https://github.com/ollewelin/libtorch-GPU-CNN-test-MNIST-with-Batchnorm

And the precision increase a little then.
Search for
”bn1”
Or
”bn2”
In this code you find.
Installation at Ubuntu with GPU and Libtorch + OpenCV for C++ here:
https://github.com/ollewelin/torchlib-opencv-gpu